# How can I insert a cross-reference page number in Novacode DocX

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I am creating a Word document using Novacode DocX in which I want to insert a piece of text, and then later on in the document insert a reference to it in the form of '(see page X)' where X is dynamically generated by Word.

In Word itself, I can easily do this by creating a bookmark for the first piece of text and inserting a cross-reference where I want the page number.

I think I know how to add a bookmark using DocX, but how do I create the cross-reference? Is this even possible in DocX?

Many thanks in advance for your help, 
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddling, I finally found a way to achieve this:

```
internal void AddCrossReference(DocX doc, Paragraph p, string destination)
        {
            XNamespace ns= doc.Xml.Name.NamespaceName;
            XNamespace xmlSpace = doc.Xml.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xml");
            p = p.Append(" (see pp");
            p.Xml.Add(new XElement(ns + "r", new XElement(ns + "fldChar", new XAttribute(ns + "fldCharType", "begin"))));
            p.Xml.Add(new XElement(ns + "r", new XElement(ns + "instrText", new XAttribute(xmlSpace + "space", "preserve"), String.Format(" PAGEREF {0} \\h ", destination))));
            p.Xml.Add(new XElement(ns + "r", new XElement(ns + "fldChar", new XAttribute(ns + "fldCharType", "separate"))));
            p.Xml.Add(new XElement(ns + "r", new XElement(ns + "rPr", new XElement(ns + "noProof")), new XElement(ns + "t", "1")));
            p.Xml.Add(new XElement(ns + "r", new XElement(ns + "fldChar", new XAttribute(ns + "fldCharType", "end"))));
            p = p.Append(")");
        }
```

`destination` is the name of the bookmark you want to cross-reference.

Any suggested improvements would be most welcome.